# how to show a custom popup message when mouse hovers on a text box in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup, alert

I am new to .Net. I would like to show a pop up alert message to the user when the cursor is placed in the text box (Custom URL) on one of the pages using C#.
The alert message should say something like "Warning: Any URL entered will be saved to the Database and will be displayed in the Employee page."

Once the user selects "OK" the message should disappear and the user can either proceed to enter the content into the field or can choose not to edit that field.

How do I go about doing this?

This is what I entered in my JS. But I am not getting the pop up message:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      function AlertForUrl() 
      { 
         var strwarning = "Warning! Any URL entered will be saved to the database and will now display in the email" ; 

         var field = document.getElementById('YourField'); 
         field.onmouseover = function() { alert(strwarning); 
             // only show once 
         field.onmouseover = undefined; 
      }; 
</script>
```

Comment: Welcolm to Stack Overflow! You need to post the code that you have written so far and let us know where the issue with it is. Nobody here will write the complete thing for you.

Comment: You can use jquery to do this simply with the focus event.  This is independent of what server side language you use and unless you use ajax, c# will not help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want the message to show once, you can use the [`mouseover` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onmouseover).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="yourField" />
```

JS:

```
var field = document.getElementById('yourField');
field.onmouseover = function () {
    alert('Warning!');

    // only show once
    field.onmouseover = undefined;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X4UbC/

Comment: As I said I am new to .net hence needed some pointers as to how to proceed.
Yes. I want the message to show only once. Will try this out and post my code. 


Thanks for all your valuable inputs.

Comment: I am using the following JS similar to the one that you posted. But I am not getting the warning message. What Am I doing wrong? Here's my script:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  function AlertForUrl()
  {
                   var strwarning = "Warning! Any URL entered will be saved to the database and will now display in the email" ;

              var field = document.getElementById('YourField');
                   field.onmouseover = function() {
                                           alert(strwarning);
                   // only show once
                   field.onmouseover = undefined;
                };

        </script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function AlertForUrl() { var strwarning = "Warning! Any URL entered will be saved to the database and will now display in the email" ; var field = document.getElementById('YourField'); field.onmouseover = function() { alert(strwarning); // only show once field.onmouseover = undefined; }; </script>

Comment: This is what I entered in my JS. But I am not getting the pop up message. What am I doing wrong? PLease help. Thanks.

      <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function AlertForUrl() 
      { 
         var strwarning = "Warning! Any URL entered will be saved to the database and will now display in the email" ; 

         var field = document.getElementById('YourField'); 
         field.onmouseover = function() { alert(strwarning); 
             // only show once 
         field.onmouseover = undefined; 
      }; 
      </script>

Comment: @Ditty is "YourField" the name of the ID attribute on your text box?

Comment: Yes. I did put my ID attribute of my textbox as YourField

Answer (score 0):

There are many javascript libraries out there that can do this. I personally like [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

Or

just google javascript tool tip